# Disappearing iron and tools?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I had crafted an iron pick axe, an iron sword, an iron axe and shears. I put them all in my chest and went to bed, when I woke up all my iron tools and iron ingots were gone. I checked my inventory and the chest multiple times then restarted the app. This didn’t happen with anything but the iron. Where did all my iron go?

Comment: Is your game accessible for any other player? Also, did you went to bed in game or in real life? If in real life, is there any possibility someone logged in using your account to make you a joke?

Comment: Did you make sure to save and quit? If you just turned off your device, it may not have saved what you have done.